# Angular 4 Dependency Injection

Tags: angular, dependency-injection

I want to reuse a function in Angular which can change the property (same type) of multiple components. The first solution is to import this function as a global variable.

Utilis.ts

```
 export function alterProperty(property: CustomProperty) {
    .... // some change on property
 }
```

component.ts

```
import {alterProperty} from './Utilis.ts'
class MyComponent {
    property1: CustomProperty;
    constructor(){}
    handleClick() {
      alterProperty(this.property1);
    }
}
```

---

After I have read some articles about Angular Dependency Injection, I've realised that this may not be a good solution, so I have figured out another solution.

myService.ts

```
@Injectable()
export class MyService1 {
    constructor(){}
    alterProperty(property: CustomProperty)
}
```

component.ts

```
import MyService1 from 'myService.ts'
@Component{
    providers: [MyService1]
}
export class MyComponent {
   property1: CustomProperty;
   constructor(private service1:MyService1){}
   handleClick(){
      this.service1.alterProperty(this.property1);
   }
}
```

---

Here is my Question:

1. Is it the right way to organise reusable functions in Angular?
2. Is it the right way that I change property1 of MyComponen somewhere else(In this example, to change the property1 by calling alterProperty function from myService Dependency) (It gives me a feeling that I lost the control of property1). Is there some more elegant way to solve it?

Appreciate for any suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

Answer 1. ) You can have a service or utility in the shared directory under src. A function in this service will take care of altering the property.

Answer 2. ) AFAIK, having a shared service is an efficient solution. This will be injected into components whenever required. There may be better solutions but this one is not incorrect either.